# Singleton classes

Tags: java, c++, singleton

Is there any difference between a Singleton class and a class with
all static members (i.e. methods and attributes).

I could not find any instance where 'all static member class' would not achieve
the same functionality as class properly implementing Singleton pattern?

For eg. `java.lang.Runtime` is a proper Singleton class whereas java.lang.System has all static method for access and merely has a private constructor to avoid external construction . Does anybody know why classes like `Runtime` are made `Singleton` and not implemented like `java.lang.System`.

Is it merely because it would be a cleaner design (i.e. mimics an object more realistically) or is there some performance benefit here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference - a singleton can implement an interface.

Also, what looks like a singleton from the outside can actually be *implemented* via different classes, where the singleton access method (e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime()`) can create the right instance at execution time. I'm not saying that's what's happened here, but it's an option.

Comment: wow, you got 3 upvotes in less than a minute. Do you have followers or something?

Comment: @Default - that's a good one! I guess it helps being Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: @Default Look at his rep. He has worked hard to be "the man" in this "community". ;-)

Comment: stalkers of Jon Skeet club, i'm member.

Comment: @InsertNickHere I know of [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) but I bet he wants a challenge like the rest of us. 3 upvotes for (first answer || being Jon Skeet || one line of text [which it was]).. well..

Comment: This is definitely the key difference. One more thing is that a singleton usually has a defined 'starting' point (e.g. first access), which may be critical if it has dependencies to other services.

Comment: I'm talking like Jon isn't here. Sorry about that Jon. +1, nice answer :)

Comment: @Default:  It's a good answer.  I'm not up voting though, he mustn't be greedy.

Comment: @JeremyP: That's okay, upvotes don't make any difference to me for the rest of the day anyway... (well, other than for badges I guess)

Comment: @Jon  Skeet: glad to be of no service :-)

Comment: @Default Skeet has reached the point of rep singularity.  If votes get too close to his event horizon they get sucked in, never to be seen again.  I know, we're all butthurt about it.  However, take heart.  Due to the Reputation Mechanical Uncertainty Principle, his rep will eventually evaporate.  Its called Skeet Radiation.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can serialize and unserialize an object (and thus a Singleton) using the Serializable interface (on Java), but not a static class.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is instantiated once.

A static class is never instantiated.

Comment: This depends on the language. In Java for example, the class is instantiated when it's loaded by the classloader and may have static initialization blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose for singletons cited by the [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) is to provide a polymorphic service, where the singleton is an abstract base class, and the concrete type is decided at runtime. And, of course, there must only be one of them in the program.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no difference between what you call a singleton and a class with all static methods/members in principle. In fact, I think that creating a class with all static members is a way of implementing the singleton idiom. Well, maybe in Java there is some kind of serious difference, but I'm speaking from the C++ point of view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask what's different between final class with private constructor and static class.
Because singleton is a class and implementation depends on programmer who programs this class.
It's same as ask what's differences between an object and static class.

Answer (score 0):

A class can be extended to create another singleton (e.g. for testing purposes), or non-singleton class. static methods cannot be overidden, they can only be hidden in a sub class.

Answer (score 0):

A common use for singletons with lazy initialization (aka Meyers singletons) is to control the order of static objects initialization (which, in C++, is undefined across different translation units). In this respect, singletons just behave like global objects, but whose order of construction behaves well.

It becomes quite difficult to control the order of destruction though. If you must rely on the singletons being destructed in some particular order (eg. a singleton logging class which should outlast other singleton instances), see Alexandrescu's book to witness the difficulty.