# Is System class singleton, abstract or what?

Tags: java, singleton, system, localdate

A class like `LocalDate` is immutable, it has a private constructor and each time we want an object of it, we have to call it's static methods, like `LocalDate.now()` or `LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`. These methods use `new` keyword and call that private constructor, so each time a "new reference" is created. It is not a singleton class because we can have multiple objects at the same time.

But what about `System` class? It looks like `LocalDate`, it has a private constructor, but it doesn't have a static method to call that. This class, also is not abstract, so why java programmers wrote `System` class like nobody can make an object of it? What is the design pattern behind it? Which classes act like this?

Comment: Why would you want to instantiate `System`? Anyway, if you want a definition you could call it an utility class. Nothing more than a bunch of related methods.

Comment: `System` is a meant to be static namespace to put some static methods and fileds related to the _system_, but since java can only have methods in a class it is a class with only a private constructor that nobody can use. It is not meant to be instantiated, but it also not meant to be inherited heance not abstract. To better model the intention for a constuct like this the language C# can declare static classes that do not have any constuctor, but java does not have such a thing.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't want to instantiate it. I wanna know why it can't be instantiated?
And thanks, I was looking for it's name: "utility class"

Comment: @MohammadKholghi I didn't mean you in particular. I meant "why should it be instantiated in the first place?" There's no need for it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Aha. I'm learning java, and never paid attention to this. Today I found that this can happen, and wanted to know why:) What about System.out.println()? I mean if I had an object of `System` class, I didn't have to call the whole class every time, for a regular print.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi `println` is not a method of `System`, but of [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) which `System.out` is an instance of. So there is something that has been instantiated. You just don't need to do it explicitly :)

Comment: Related: [Singleton classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448047/singleton-classes)

Answer (score 1):

It has a private constructor which is never called, so there are never any instances (singleton would require one).

```
/** Don't let anyone instantiate this class */
private System() {
}
```

It is not abstract

```
public final class System {
```

`System` is used more like a namespace. It's just a container for a bunch of static methods and constants.

Java does not allow you to put methods outside of a class so sometimes the result is a completely uninstantiated "class" like this.